# datepicker not wokring with form repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

my date picker is working fine when I try to clone date picker  input the cloned date picker
is not working

```
    function repeatDatePicker() {
        $('.ka-datepicker').each(function() {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    }
```

I tried to call this function after cloning input but didn't work

This is how i clone my code

```
        $(".owner-item-0").clone().appendTo(".owners-group").removeClass("owner-item-0")
            .removeClass("d-none").addClass("owner-item-" + ownersLoop)
            .find("input[type='text']").val("");
```

My Date Picker Code

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ka-datepicker').datepicker();
    });
```

The Cloned Data picker is working if i deleted the code above but i needet it in inialize the first date picker

Comment: Invoking `datepicker()` on the elements after you clone them is absolutely the correct approach to fix the problem. If it's not working for you then there's other issues which need to be resolved. However as you've not shown any more of your code, we can't offer any useful assistance.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have updated my code please check it

Comment: When are you calling the `repeatDatePicker()` function?

Comment: after the cloning code 

        $(".owner-item-0").clone().appendTo(".owners-group").removeClass("owner-item-0")
            .removeClass("d-none").addClass("owner-item-" + ownersLoop)
            .find("input[type='text']").val("");
 
        repeatDatePicker();